# NameError: name 'PostCreateView' is not defined

Tags: python, django

I'm using Django 3.0.8 I'm getting an error in `path('post/new/',PostCreateView.as_view(),name='post-create')` in blog/urls.py(blog is an app under my django_project). I've a class named PostCreateView in blog/views.py but it throws NameError:name 'PostCreateView' is not defined.

My blog/views.py is here:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView, CreateView
from .models import Post

# Create your views here.
def home(request):
    context={
        'posts':Post.objects.all()
    }
    return render(request,'blog\home.html',context)

class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name='blog/home.html'   # <app>/<model>_<viewtype>.html
    context_object_name='posts'
    ordering=['-date_posted']

class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post

class PostCreatelView(CreateView):
    model = Post
    fields=['title','content']
    

def about(request):
    return render(request,'blog\about.html',{'title':'About'})
```

and blog/urls.py is here:

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import PostListView, PostDetailView, PostCreatelView
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('',PostListView.as_view(),name='blog-home'),
    path('post/<int:pk>',PostDetailView.as_view(),name='post-detail'),
    path('post/new/',PostCreateView.as_view(),name='post-create'),
    path('about/',views.about,name='blog-about'),
]
```

What is wrong with this code?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared `PostCreatelView` (with an "l") not `PostCreateView`.